# LAN setup advice with a Billion 7800N

Tags: networking, lan

I have 1 Billion 7800N router
2 windows 7 pcs
2 android phones through WLAN
3 android tablets through WLAN
and a HP N54L running Windows SBS 2011 Essentials

Now the server will be needed as a file server, domain controller and for ICS. What I want to do is share the files and internet through the server, so that the other devices only have internet access through the server.

I am no expert but the best I can think of is a VLAN for the devices and the server on the real LAN using 2 NICs. Is that correct, or is there another way or a better way, apart from using another router/switch?.

From what I have read, the 7800N won't do the separation that I need and that the VLAN is only for IpTV, which would mean I need to get another router.

Comment: What's going to be the DHCP server for the other devices? The router or the server? This sounds like a poor choice of setups to me. You really want to let the router do the routing.

Comment: I am assuming the router will be the DHCP server or maybe the Windows Server. What do you think David, what would you suggest?

Comment: You do realize if you let your server acting as internet gateway (ICS), and file server, and domain controller, means your server is exposed to the outside world. Are you sure you want that kind of mission critical (to your home network) server to be accessible from outside world?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just going to use a software security suite like Kaspersky Small Office but that probabaly wont be enough will it?. What about if I set up another cheap pc with untangle on it after the router in bridge mode?. Do I need another switch for the server to use the server as a internet gateway or can I just plug it into the router?

Comment: I guess a more accurate question is if I plug the server, the pcs etc via ethernet, and the other devices via wlan into a firewall device like a netgear fvs318g or a pc with untangle on it can the devices connect to the domain and the internet?. Because to connect to the domain the dns server address needs to be the server address so therefore the internet won't work unless it is coming from the server, correct? and is that secure?